# Select MAX() and respective id

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT MAX(count),id_university FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(*) as count, id_university FROM `users` 
    where status = 2 AND id_university>0 
    GROUP BY id_university
)AS counts
```

Currently above query gives me id_university = 1 instead the respective value.

How can I get the respective id_university with the maximum count?

Comment: live with whatever tie-break strategy you implement (or don't)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count, id_university
FROM users
WHERE status = 2 AND id_university > 0
GROUP BY id_university
ORDER BY count DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Oh dang, yes that's it. How stupid I am...Thanks a lot for the quick answer.